# CSS styles are not applying to Jquery Mobile Pages

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to add a few css styles to a Jquery Mobile page. When I click on the link it loads the page, but not the css styles I added. It does load the css styles that I added if I refresh the page. Not sure what I'm missing. Anyone know how to get the styles to load? I posted the link below to show what I'm working on.

Comment: Can you please past some code ?

Comment: You know what? I am too experiencing this weird behavior past few weeks. Those cdn libraries don't load at first time and do get after a refresh. Another time my FF console showed something related to Cross-Domain problem when I was developing a site on localhost(Xampp).

Comment: Is this a problem if someone could know : Error: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js is being assigned a //# sourceMappingURL, but already has one

Comment: the head doesn't refresh itself page to page in jqm... try adding the css to your main style sheet, reload and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery mobile only loads `<head>` tag once when whole document is loaded. After the document is loaded if you will click on other links then only content part will be refreshed through ajax along with data transition effect.
Hence either add all your css script in a file and add it into head tag or stop loading other pages through ajax using following option:

```
<a href="#" data-ajax=”false”>Without Ajax</a>
```

But if you will disable content loading using ajax then link will work as it works in normal webpage and also transition effect will be not exist.